# How to configure this function User-Agent?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I configure a user agent for this function? I have tried a few things but I can't seem to do it. The functions scrapes links from a given link in the arguments. The main part of the program repeats this function for every entry in the links list.

The idea is the program will jump from link to link scanning for links. The problem I am having is after about 1500 links I am running into the HTTPError 403 Forbidden. Apparently this is due to server settings rejecting the urllib request from the Python user agent.

```
# Create a connection, (starting point)
def scrape_links(a_link):
    """Scrape links from a URL"""
    links = []
    html = urlopen(a_link)
    bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser");

    for link in bs_obj.find_all('a'):
        url = (link.get('href'))
        try:
            if url[0:7] == 'http://' or url[0:8] == 'https://':
                print(url)
                links += [url]
        except TypeError:
            print('Skipping link...')
    return links
```

Comment: I don't know why but some of the code is not in the code box, it is above

Comment: I'll edit, it's the indenting to indicate a code block

Comment: Thank you that looks a lot more readable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add some kind of user agent, and perhaps a pause between grabbing links.  You can get `403`'d for a lot of reasons:

I would suggest using the `request` module, I've just had much better luck with it.  Something along these lines:

```
import time
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_links(a_link):
    print("pausing 1 second between URL hits..")
    time.sleep(1)
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = requests.get(a_link, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
    ...the rest
```

It's a little different then what you have, but this *should* get you going in the right direction.  You may have to try different headers, or what has also worked for me is to just name my user-agent `super-bot 9000` or something.  Sometimes the site just wants to know that you are actually a bot.  Whole jobs are built around parsing and gathering web data, it's tricky!

Comment: Would there be a way to just add an exception for the error to keep it running?

Comment: Sure, so you can check the response code.  I usually do something like if `r.status_code != 200` return out of the function and have it skip the URL

Comment: Brilliant! It seems to just keep going now. I didn't add the exception in the end. Now to add some code so I don't scan links more than once. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Happy to help :)